# Using advice-add to redefine a function call within another function

Tags: advice, cl

The function `outshine-cycle` (part of [Outshine](https://github.com/alphapapa/outshine)) calls the function `indent-relative`.  I would like that instead, it called the function `indent-for-tab-command`.

To do this, I want to advise the function `outshine-cycle`.  I imagine this could look like the following (which is not working):

```
(defun my-indent (orig-fun &rest args)
  (cl-flet ((indent-relative () (indent-for-tab-command)))))

(advice-add 'outshine-cycle :around #'my-indent)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun YOUR/fn ()
  (YOUR/insert))

(defun YOUR/insert ()
  (insert "233"))

(advice-add 'YOUR/fn :around
            (lambda (fn &rest args)
              (let ((old-def (symbol-function 'YOUR/insert)))
                (unwind-protect
                    (progn
                      (fset 'YOUR/insert (lambda ()
                                           (insert "42")))
                      (apply fn args))
                  (fset 'YOUR/insert old-def)))))

(YOUR/fn)
;; => 42
```

---

Why doesn't your code work?

1. You used `advice-add` incorrectly: you didn't call the original function from `my-indent`.  Please see the manual for yourself.
2. `cl-flet` "*make **local** function definitions*" (quoted from its docstring).  `macroexpand` the `cl-flet` form then you will find it doesn't change the definition of function `YOUR/insert` at all.